# Inserting a NHibernate object without obtaining references to all of its children objects

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Let's pick an example model as a reference:

```
public class Cat{
    public long Id;
    public string Name;
    public IEnumerable<Cat> Friends; //ManyToMany
}
```

Note that this is the simplest possible model I can describe.

Currently, in order to insert a new `Cat` with its `Friends` I must first obtain their full persisted objects. For example..

```
Cat sally = Repository.GetByName("Sally").First(); //The first cat named Sally
Cat mary = new Cat{ Name="Mary, Friends = new Cat[] {sally} };

Repository.Save(mary); //Which is Session.Save(mary);
```

This works fine as soon as sally is in the current scope. But in web environments, considering that I'm working in MVC, I don't necessarily keep all persisted objects in memory. Think about a page where I can create the new cat and select the children from a multiselect list...

If the MVC controller returns me only the cats' IDs (which is what I want) I can't do the following otherwise I get a duplicate entry exception

```
Cat mary = new Cat{ Name="Mary, Friends = new Cat[] {new Cat{ Id = 1}, new Cat{Id=2}... };

Repository.Save(mary); //Boom, because it tries to persist the new children with duplicate IDs
```

Instead I must

```
long[] ids;
IEnumerable<Cat> friends = from cat in Repository.Query() where Id in ids select cat; //Which does a SELECT query
Cat mary = new Cat{ Name="Mary", Friends = friends };

Repository.Save(mary); //Which runs fine;
```

Now my question is: given that at a certain time I know the **primary keys** of a collection of already persisted objects, how can I insert a new object that has references to the objects of the collection **without querying the DB to get them all**?

I understand that NHibernate has cache, so often querying the `Session` for a known ID doesn't fire a full query, but I'd like to know more about the power of NHibernate.

Since the question is made for example purposes, don't mind if I don't care about the inverse relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have the ids, all you need to do is use `session.Load` to get references without loading them from the db.

Just change your second line to the following:

```
var friends = from id in ids select session.Load<Cat>(id);
```